# Capture "call end" event using Ionic, React Native, NativeScript, and Flutter?

Tags: react-native, ionic-framework, events, flutter, nativescript

The scenario:

1. For both iOS and Android, capture a "call-end" (hangup) event.
2. Use the captured event to trigger an options window.

What would the differences be to do this using Ionic, React Native, NativeScript, and Flutter?

Comment: I believe it is going to be the same if the implementation is on the android side.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing a feature for Ionic, ReactNative, and Flutter are more or less same. You must probably write a plugin where you will have to implement the feature in native languages (Objective C / Java) and interface them with JavaScript for Ionic & ReactNative / Dart for Flutter.

But it's quite different with NativeScript as it has a **JavaScript runtime that has 100% access to all device apis**. You may write a plugin if you are willing to reuse the code or just directly access any api within your project using just JavaScript. If you use TypeScript, life will be even more easier with the typings for all the native apis.

[Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EjWqTangPiM) that briefly discusses the differences between these platforms.

Comment: Hi @manoj, thanks for your answer.  I was looking more for specific details, and seeing different examples from the different options.  It's actually disappointing to hear that Ionic, React Native, and Flutter require native plugins, since these target non-native developers.  How would you implement this in NativeScript?

Comment: Here is how you would marshal [Objective C](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/ios-runtime/Marshalling-Overview) / [Java](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/marshalling/java-to-js) code into JavaScript with {N}.